# AJAX C# AutoCompleteExtender contextKey

Tags: ajax, autocompleteextender

How do you dynamically pass parameter/control to contextKey?

```
<asp:TextBox ID="tbA" runat="server" autocomplete="off"></asp:TextBox> 
<asp:TextBox ID="tbB" runat="server">hello</asp:TextBox> 
<asp:TextBox ID="tbC" runat="server">world</asp:TextBox>

<cc1:AutoCompleteExtender ID="aceListA" ServiceMethod="myListServiceA" ServicePath="WebService.asmx" TargetControlID="tbA" runat="server" EnableCaching="true" UseContextKey="true"> </cc1:AutoCompleteExtender>

  [WebMethod]
   public string[] myListServiceA(string prefixText, int count, string contextKey)
```

Because I want to check tbB, tbC at Web Service level.
I've read this [article](http://www.aspdotnetcodes.com/AutoComplete_Textbox_Addtional_Parameters.aspx"article") like 5 times, but still doesn't make a sense out of it, per half missing complete codes.

Comment: I don't think it is a good idea for the webservice to have to check tbB, tbC etc. Why don't you create overloads with appropriate names, each of which can be applied to specific case?

Comment: what about just pass multiple parameters?
ie: listAs?a=hello&b=world, this is typical ajax passing.
But i am trying to achieve passing it in keyContext before AutoCompleteExtender is being called, can you please post an example if possible.
Thanks

Answer (score 6):

You can set the context key in two ways:

Client-Side, through Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function SetContextKey()
    {
        $find('auJobs').set_contextKey('moo');
        return;
    }

</script>  `
```

or
on the server side
auJobs.ContextKey = "Whatever You need to put in here"

Terry

Comment: I meant to add, 'auJobs' is the IDof your autocomplete extender.  You can also give your autocomplete extender a BehaviorID and use that instead of the id to find it. Hope this helps