# AutoCompleteExtender - authentication failure (forms authentication)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, forms-authentication

I'm using the AutoCompleteExtender from the AJAX control toolkit on my aspx page - I have it wired up to a WCF service that is returning a string array and everything works happily.

If I change my service definition to include a demand for the caller to be authenticated, like so:

```
<OperationContract(), PrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Authenticated:=True)> _
Public Function GetLookupValues(ByVal prefixText As String, ByVal count As Integer, ByVal contextKey As String) As String()
```

Then the autocomplete extender stops working, and I get an authentication error in the service.   The service is set up to use ASPNetCompatibility mode, and I was hoping that the extender would pass the authentication credentials for my logged in user - does anyone know how to make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case anybody finds this and is curious, I wound up switching back to an 'old' style (asmx) web service and that worked just fine.

Answer (score 1):

The sample over [here](http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/Samples/AutoComplete/AutoComplete.aspx) mentions a ContextKey property on the AutoCompleteExtender.  Does the behaviour change if you set this property on the extender?

Also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1440552/ajax-c-autocompleteextender-contextkey) StackOverflow post might have some answers.

Comment: I'm not sure that this really answers the question - I'm already passing a context key, which is what the other post deals with - my problem is with the authentication.