# Passing parameters when using AutoCompleteExtender

Tags: asp.net, autocompleteextender

How to pass parameters to the service method when using the AutoCompleteExtender?

Answer (score 1):

Use `ContextKey` property of the `AutocompleteExtender`

See this link: [AJAX C# AutoCompleteExtender contextKey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1440552/ajax-c-autocompleteextender-contextkey)