# AutoComplete with context key in a Textbox based on two parameters?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, web-services, asp.net-ajax

[image]

Refer the Image, having 2 `TextBox`(`tbxAttribute and tbxAttributeDesc`).
Value will be loaded when page is loaded in `tbxAttribute TextBox`.In  `tbxAttributeDesc  TextBox` the end user will Fill that Data.

I have already Completed the `Autocomplete Text` in `tbxAttributeDesc`.
We are maintaining these Values in a table, Based up on the loaded `tbxAttribute` value  their corresponding `AttributeDesc` will be highlight into `tbxAttributeDesc Textbox`

My Code be:

```
autoDesc = new AjaxControlToolkit.AutoCompleteExtender();

autoDesc.ID = "autoDesc" + i; 

autoDesc.BehaviorID = "tbxAtribute" + i;

autoDesc.ServicePath = "itemvaluemas.asmx";

autoDesc.ServiceMethod = "GetAttributeDesc";

autoDesc.TargetControlID = tbxAttributeDesc.ID;

autoDesc.MinimumPrefixLength = 1;

autoDesc.CompletionInterval = 10; 

autoDesc.FirstRowSelected = true;

autoDesc.CompletionSetCount = 30;

autoDesc.UseContextKey = true;
```

and also used Javscript Concept.

Refer the Below Image:

[image]

Here i need to pass condition as `tbxAtribute` and their Corresponding `tbxAtributeDesc`, based up on that `tbxAbbr` Value need to be highlight..

if i use `ContextKey` then how i pass these two textbox value in a context key..

If you have any idea please help to solve this problem.

Comment: i think it's hard to understand what do you mean, can you explain with some code examples?

Comment: if we search in Google Seach- if we enter 'A' then the google engine shows the list of options starts letter 'A'.. As the same concept i need to implement in my textbox.. But here based up on the tbxAttribute textbox the coresponding attributedesc will be shown..

Comment: i think you need, to implement javascript observer, that will watch over the two textboxes and will handle the text change interaction.

Comment: @PrinceAntonyG please show the code you currently use to retreive the list of autcomplete values. The most probable solution is that you alter the method that provides these values, so that it can accept an `Attribute` string, based upon which it returns the possible values. So instead of `GetAutoCompleteValues(AttributeDescriptionTextBox.Text)`, call `GetAutoCompleteValues(AttributeTextBox.Text, AttributeDescriptionTextBox.Text)`.

Comment: Refer my solution below,if any one have better solution than this..Please post ur answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use ContextKey property to pass the value of textbox into GetAutoCompleteValues function.

```
txtbox1.Attributes.Add("onchange", "$find('BehaviourIDOftbxAttributeDesc').set_contextKey(tbxAttribute.value);");
```

For more information check the below links:

[AJAX C# AutoCompleteExtender contextKey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1440552/ajax-c-sharp-autocompleteextender-contextkey)

http://arrao4u.wordpress.com/2010/01/14/autocomplete-extender-with-context-key/

Answer (score 1):

This is the Solution which i found.

I use JavaScript:

```
function SetContextAbbr(formatid, itemValue, behaveid) {
var autoComplete1 = $find(behaveid);
var target = autoComplete1.get_element();
var txtformatid = document.getElementById(formatid);
var txtitemValue = document.getElementById(itemValue);
var contextkeydata = txtformatid.value + "-" + txtitemValue.value;
autoComplete1.set_contextKey(contextkeydata);
}
```

Use Function as

```
 public string[] GetItemabbr(string prefixText, int count, string contextKey)
 {
        string[] splitvalue = contextKey.Split('-');

        //code here
 }
```

In WebService

```
                    autoabbr = new AjaxControlToolkit.AutoCompleteExtender();
                    autoabbr.ID = "autoabbr" + i;
                    autoabbr.BehaviorID = "autoabbrbehave" + i;
                    autoabbr.ServicePath ="itemvaluemas.asmx";
                    autoabbr.ServiceMethod = "GetItemabbr";
                    autoabbr.TargetControlID = txtItemAbbrValue.ID;
                    autoabbr.MinimumPrefixLength = 1;
                    autoabbr.CompletionInterval = 10;
                    autoabbr.FirstRowSelected = true;
                    autoabbr.CompletionListCssClass = "completionList";
                    autoabbr.CompletionListHighlightedItemCssClass = "itemHighlighted";
                    autoabbr.CompletionListItemCssClass = "listItem";
                    autoabbr.CompletionSetCount = 30;
                    autoabbr.UseContextKey = true;
```

Comment: I m not sure this is the best answer for my requirement, But it solves my needs. It is working fine.